# ERROR: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver

Tags: java, r, rstudio, snowflake-connector

I'm using R Studio to connect to Snowflake using this code

```
# Get JDBC Driver
#Mention the classPath as where your downloaded jdbc jar file is present.
jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver",
                   classPath="/Users/EWorsh/Downloads/snowflake-jdbc-3.13.19.jar")
```

and I recieve this error:

```
Error in JDBC(driverClass = "net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver",  : 
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver
```

I'm using java version "1.8.0_333" and I've tried all the troubleshooting I can find.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with Java 11 with Snowflake JDBC connector 3.13.19, its working fine and connecting successfully with R studio.

Steps:

```
    > options(dplyr.jdbc.classpath = "/Users/sghosh/JDBC jar/snowflake-jdbc-3.13.19.jar")
    > jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver", classPath="/Users/sghosh/JDBC jar/snowflake-jdbc-3.13.19.jar")
    > jdbcConnection <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:snowflake://<account>.snowflakecomputing.com:443/?account=sfcsupport2&warehouse=WH_NAME&db=SAMPLEDATABASE&schema=TEST&tracing=All&jdbc_query_result_format=JSON&role=ADMIN", "sujanT1","password")
    > tm=proc.time()
    > result <-dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, 'select * from EMPLOYEE')
    > print(result)
      ID  NAME AGE SALARY
    1  1 sujan 100    200
    2  2  alok 500    600
```

Please try with Java 11 once.